# mysqli_error() is not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have written a `mysql_query` and it is not working.

I want to know the problem via `mysqli_error()` however it gives the following error `mysqli_error()` expects parameter 1 to be `mysqli`

my mysql code is as follows:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "", "tomuman");
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT id, to FROM messages WHERE read='0'");
```

and `mysqli_error` as follows:

```
echo mysqli_error($query);
```

What could cause this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should not use $query as a parameter for mysqli_error()

use

```
echo mysqli_error($connect);
```

Just after trying to connect you can also check for specific connection errors with:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add following code in your query to get the mysql error message.

> or die (mysqli_error($connect))

as like below

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT id, to FROM messages WHERE read='0'") or die (mysqli_error($connect));


     if ($query) {
        echo "success";
     }
     else {
          echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($connect));
     }
```